# I don't understand the concept of greatest slope in 3D, please help in understanding it, providing sample problem for my better understanding.

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

Taking the axis OZ to be vertical, find the equations of the line of **greatest slope** through the point (2,-1,0) on the plane $2x+3y-4z-1=0$

Comment: You have to know the concept of the line of greatest slope (in a 3D representation) first. See my answer to the following question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123724/what-is-the-line-of-greatest-slope-on-a-plane

Comment: Thanks you sir, I'll check it out.